# How to change logical disjunctive OR SQL query to conjunctive AND to match all input parameters in list?

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope the title somehow makes sense.

I've got 3 tables in DB. First one holds **`product_variant`** records, second one holds the **`label`** records and the third one is the **`ref`** table in between.

- `product_variant`: (id, productId, serviceProviderId).
- `label`: (id,label).
- `product_variant_label_ref`: (label_id,variant_id).

Input parameters for my query are: `productType`, `serviceProviderId` and set of labels and
my aim is to select rows in `product_variant` table based on the input parameters.

This is my query in hibernate xml file:

```
 SELECT v.*
 FROM product_variant v
     INNER JOIN product_variant_label_ref r ON v.id = r.variant_id
     INNER JOIN product_product p ON p.productType = :productType
     INNER JOIN product_label l ON l.id = r.label_id
     WHERE v.product_id = p.id
        AND v.serviceprovider_id = :serviceProviderId
        AND l.label in (:labels)
```

Problem is that with `IN` operator I am getting disjunctive `OR` selection and I want `AND` in between. If I specify different labels as an input, I want only those `product_variant` rows which have a relation to all of them through ref table. If one of the input labels doesn't belong to any `product_variant`, query should not return anything. Could anyone help me to change my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the rows returned for each product, and match it to the number of items in your labels parameter

If you have, for example, 3 labels in your labels parameter...

```
 SELECT v.id
 FROM product_variant v 
     INNER JOIN product_variant_label_ref r ON v.id = r.variant_id 
     INNER JOIN product_product p ON p.productType = :productType 
     INNER JOIN product_label l ON l.id = r.label_id 
     WHERE v.product_id = p.id 
        AND v.serviceprovider_id = :serviceProviderId 
        AND l.label in (:labels) 
 GROUP BY v.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) = 3 -- ie: Length of labels
```